# java arraylist<string> check for the first and last value that fulfills a condition

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of strings, called `ArrayList<string> records` that stores strings of data that will be delimited by commas `,`. At the [5] position of the string (after being delimited), will be a value between 0 to 500. An example of a string of that data is as follows:

```
userA, 1418600437, 38.9047, 177.0164, washington, 180
```

so anyway, the arraylist will have many strings of similar data. What I need is to iterate through the arraylist (which is already sorted in the sequence I want), then find the FIRST value in the arraylist that fulfills the criteria that the number at position[5] is `< 200` and then the LAST value of the arraylist that fulfills the same criteria. When the first value is detected, a String will be assigned to that one record to call it the "start" value and the same for the last value. Can anyone help me with the logic, or just a pseudocode of how that might work?

Comment: Which part of this is causing you problems? First do an iteration to get the first matching record, then do a reverse iteration to get the last matching record. In both cases, break out of your iterations after you found a match.

Comment: because more than 2 records in the arraylist will fulfill the condition that the number at position 5 is lesser than 200, so i just want the first one, the moment it is found the checking will stop, and then again the last one, so the middle values won't be assigned the string!

Comment: Like I said: break out of your iterations after you found your first/last match.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen He needs to iterate over the whole `ArrayList` because the final matching value could be the last entry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's why I said: do a reverse iteration to find the last value. No need to loop over the entire list.

Comment: Like they said, iterate from beginning for the first, from the end for the last. As for finding the last element within the string, I would take the char[] for the string and reverse-iterate it from the end until the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.  The first value to match the criteria is recorded using a `boolean` flag.  The last value is updated each time the criteria matches, with the result that after the `for` loop finishes, the variable `lastValue` will store the last matching value.

```
boolean seenFirst = false;
int firstValue, lastValue;

for (String record : records) {
    String[] parts = record.split(", ");
    int value = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);

    if (value < 200)) {
        lastValue = value;
        if (!seenFirst) {
            seenFirst = true;
            firstValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, this is very simple:

```
List<string> records = new ArrayList<>();
String firstValue = records.stream().filter(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(",")[5].trim()) < 200)
                                    .findFirst().get();
String lastValue = IntStream.range(0, records.size())
                            .mapToObj(i -> records.get(records.size() - i - 1))
                            .filter(i -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(",")[5].trim()) < 200)
                            .findFirst().get();
```

To get the first value, we get the integer, filter those that are less than 200 and retrieve the first value.

To get the last value, it is the same but the iteration is done in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments: first do an iteration to get the first matching record, then do a reverse iteration to get the last matching record. In both cases, break out of your iterations after you found a match.

Could look something like this:

```
String first, last;

for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(records[i].split(", ")[5]) < 200) {
        first = records[i];
        break;
    }
}

for (int i = records.size() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(records[i].split(", ")[5]) < 200) {
        last = records[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Obviously should be refactored to get rid of the duplicated matching logic.